# Comparing 2 arrays of nested objects while ignoring some properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm looking to check an API response for against a set of values but the API response contains some additional info that I'm not interested in checking against

Data to check:

```
[
    {
        "address": {
            "city": "London",
            "firstLine": "23 High Road",
            "postCode": "WC1 1AA",
            "region": "South East",
            "uniqueIdentifier": 239


        },
        "detail": {
            "leaseholdFreehold": "Freehold",
            "location": "Satisfactory",
            "sector": "Office"

        },
        "valuation": {
            "value": "770000",
            "valuationDate": "2018-03-07",
            "yield": "7.75"
        }
    },
    {
        "address": {
            "city": "Leeds",
            "firstLinePropertyName": "45 Headrow",
            "postCode": "LS2 8AA",
            "region": "North East",
            "uniqueIdentifier": 287
        },
        "detail": {
            "leaseholdFreehold": "Freehold",
            "location": "Good",
            "sector": "Residential"

        },
        "valuation": {
            "value": "88000",
            "valuationDate": "2018-03-07",
            "yield": "8.87"
        }
    }
]
```

API response:

```
[
        {
            "address": {
                "city": "London",
                "firstLine": "23 High Road",
                "postCode": "WC1 1AA",
                "region": "South East",
                "uniqueIdentifier": 239
            },
            "detail": {
                "designAndCondition": "",
                "developmentCompletionDate": "0001-01-01",
                "leaseholdFreehold": "Freehold",
                "location": "Satisfactory",
                "sector": "Office"

            },
            "valuation": {
                "value": "770000",
                "valuationDate": "2018-03-07",
                "yield": "7.75"
            },
            "dbIdentifier": 240
        },
        {
            "address": {
                "city": "Leeds",
                "firstLinePropertyName": "11 Main Road",
                "postCode": "LS2 8AA",
                "region": "North East",
                "uniqueIdentifier": 282
            },
            "detail": {
                "designAndCondition": "",
                "developmentCompletionDate": "0001-01-01",
                "leaseholdFreehold": "Freehold",
                "location": "Good",
                "sector": "Residential"

            },
            "valuation": {
                "value": "88000",
                "valuationDate": "2018-03-07",
                "yield": "8.75"
            },
            "dbIdentifier": 239
        }
]
```

So I'm not interested in what values are returned for `dbIdentifier`, `designAndCondition` and  `developmentCompletionDate` as they are not in my data to check against but I would like to compare the values for the rest of the properties. In practice these arrays will have more than 2 items

I was initially thinking I would remove the unwanted properties from the objects using the function below

```
const newArray = responseBody.map(({ dbIdentifierIdentifier, detail: { designAndCondition, developmentCompletionDate  }, ...rest }) => rest)
```

Then ordering by `address.uniqueIdentifier`, converting to JSON strings and comparing the strings but the function above doesn't work with the nested properties as `newArray` doesn't contain the `detail` object at all

`newArray`:

```
[
        {
            "address": {
                "city": "London",
                "firstLine": "23 High Road",
                "postCode": "WC1 1AA",
                "region": "South East",
                "uniqueIdentifier": 239
            },
            "valuation": {
                "value": "770000",
                "valuationDate": "2018-03-07",
                "yield": "7.75"
            },
            "dbIdentifier": 240
        },
        {
            "address": {
                "city": "Leeds",
                "firstLinePropertyName": "11 Main Road",
                "postCode": "LS2 8AA",
                "region": "North East",
                "uniqueIdentifier": 282
            },
            "valuation": {
                "value": "88000",
                "valuationDate": "2018-03-07",
                "yield": "8.75"
            },
            "dbIdentifier": 239
        }
]
```

IS it possible to do it the above way by passing a destructured nested object a map function?

Comment: If you're open to use lodash you can deep merge the object in your current approach with [\_.merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge) and also omit selected properties with [\_.omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit).

Comment: @JonathanNielsen I would prefer a non library solution

Answer (score 1):

One way to remove the unwanted properties from the API response would be to first copy the response into a new array (to preserve the original response), then delete the properties:

```js
const apiResponse = [{
    "address": {
      "city": "London",
      "firstLine": "23 High Road",
      "postCode": "WC1 1AA",
      "region": "South East",
      "uniqueIdentifier": 239
    },
    "detail": {
      "designAndCondition": "",
      "developmentCompletionDate": "0001-01-01",
      "leaseholdFreehold": "Freehold",
      "location": "Satisfactory",
      "sector": "Office"

    },
    "valuation": {
      "value": "770000",
      "valuationDate": "2018-03-07",
      "yield": "7.75"
    },
    "dbIdentifier": 240
  },
  {
    "address": {
      "city": "Leeds",
      "firstLinePropertyName": "11 Main Road",
      "postCode": "LS2 8AA",
      "region": "North East",
      "uniqueIdentifier": 282
    },
    "detail": {
      "designAndCondition": "",
      "developmentCompletionDate": "0001-01-01",
      "leaseholdFreehold": "Freehold",
      "location": "Good",
      "sector": "Residential"

    },
    "valuation": {
      "value": "88000",
      "valuationDate": "2018-03-07",
      "yield": "8.75"
    },
    "dbIdentifier": 239
  }
]

let apiResponseCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(apiResponse))

var newArray = apiResponseCopy.map(i => {
  delete i.dbIdentifier
  delete i.detail.designAndCondition
  delete i.detail.developmentCompletionDate

  return i
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Then, you should be able to compare the newArray against your data.

Comment: this would work but I believe delete has some impact on performance